# Save form's inputs when user proceed to next form

Tags: html, forms

I have a very long form, so I need to separate it to different pages.

My questions are:

1) How to save the form input when the user navigate to next form, and when the user back to previous form, the data entered previously will still be there.

2) How can I save the data of the incomplete form and provide the user a link so that he can  go to that link and continue to fill in the form before actually submit it.

Please advise me on how to achieve these. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Simply submit the form to next form page and in next form page you can populate hidden fields with the received data from form1

form2.php

```
$form1Field = $_POST;
```

form2.php

```
<form action="form3.php">
    <input id='form1_name' type='hidden' value='<?=form1Field['name']?>' />
    <input id='form12_email' type='text' value='' />
</form>
```

@katti's suggestion is good, easy way is to make `divs` for each form and hide using `css` "display:none" all `divs` except 1st, then on a click button, hide div1 and show div2 so on. that way you wont need many form and will need less code and faster solution.

Comment: I agreed that katti's suggestion is better. Thanks to your suggestion too!

Comment: Therenho you can proceed as @Bsienn says.
This question is more of how to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use hidden fields for this purpose. Or save data in cookies.

Comment: Not sure will save data in cookie works well but I will try. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can divide the form by dynamically loading the next part of the form using JavaScript.
And it is a better user experience too not loading a new page completely.
In this case you can save the form content in a JSON object which can be posted to the server once the user hits submit.

Comment: Great idea. Never thought of that before. How about my second question? I want to do like what done by 123contactform: http://www.123contactform.com/web-form-builder/ but I have no idea how to do it. Any suggestion? Thanks!